# Implementing curl in ZF2

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, curl, zend-framework2

I am trying to establish a communication with two `zf2` application via `curl`.The required response is in `xml`. So far I could establish the connection and `xml` is returned as response.

**The problem**

The problem is that,I can't iterate on my `xml response`.Whenever I var_dump and view source code of my `$response->getContent`,I get as

```
string(142) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myxml>
<login>
<status>success</status>
<Err>None</Err>
</login>
</myxml>
"
```

and when I simply `var_dump` my `$response`,I get an `object(Zend\Http\Response)#440`.

`simplexml_load_string($response->getContent())` gives me a blank page.

Also `print $data->asXML()` gives me `Call to a member function asXML() on a non-object` error.What am I doing wrong here?

**Curl request action**

```
    $request = new \Zend\Http\Request();
    $request->getHeaders()->addHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    ]);
    $request->setUri('http://localhost/app1/myaction');
    $request->setMethod('POST'); //uncomment this if the POST is used
    $request->getPost()->set('curl', 'true');
    $request->getPost()->set('email', 'me@gmail.com');
    $request->getPost()->set('password', '2014');

    $client = new Client;
    $client->setAdapter("Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl");

    $response = $client->dispatch($request);

    var_dump($response);//exit;
    //$response = simplexml_load_string($response->getContent());
    //echo $response;exit;
    return $response;
```

**Curl response action**

```
         $php_array=array(
         'login'=>array(
         'status'=>'failed','Err'=>'Unauthorised Access'
         )
         );
         $Array2XML=new \xmlconverter\Arraytoxml;
         $xml = $Array2XML->createXML('myxml', $php_array);
         $xml = $xml->saveXML();
         //echo $xml;exit;
            $response = new \Zend\Http\Response();
            $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
            $response->setContent($xml);
            return $response;
```

The `Array2XML` can be found [here](http://www.lalit.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Array2XML.txt?ver=0.8)

Any ideas?

Comment: simplexml_load_string returns an object SimpleXMLElement

Comment: If you're getting a blank page, you have display errors turned off (which is the ZF default). Check the web server error log to see what the actual error is.

Comment: have you tried using raw CURL instead of zf2 adapter?

Comment: @Conti,I got it worked with the same code,with the zf2 adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I simply var_dump my $response,I get an object(Zend\Http\Response)#440

This is correct and it tells you the type of `$response`.

> simplexml_load_string($response->getContent()) gives me a blank page.

This is correct because despite this function can return a value expressible to an empty string, it does not create any output on it's own and therefore the blank page is to be expected.

> Any ideas?

First of all you should formulate a proper problem statement with your question. All you say so far therein is to be expected, so your question is not clear at best.

Second you need to do proper error handling and do some safe programming:

```
$buffer = $response->getContent();
if (!is_string($buffer) || !strlen($buffer) || $buffer[0] !== '<') {
    throw new RuntimeException('Need XML string, got %s', var_export($buffer, 1));
}
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
if (false === $xml) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Unable to parse response string as XML');
}
```

Which is: For every parameter you get, validate it. For every function or method result you receive check the post-conditions. Before you call a function or method, check the pre-conditions for each parameter.

Log errors to file and handle uncaught exceptions.

As an additional idea: Drop the use of the array to XML function and replace it with a library that is maintained. In your case it's perhaps easier to just use SimpleXML your own to create the XML.